# html li background-color for list markers too

Tags: html, html-lists

What I need to do, if I want to highlight with background color not only li element, but list marker too? (watch illustation)

[image]

Thanks for answer.

Comment: you want to put color on the bullet points too?

Comment: `list-style-position: inside; padding-left: 2em;` maybe? Adjust the `padding` to taste.

Comment: can you show us your html and css? sure it'd be easy just to target li { } in the css but that will then affect every li in the page.

Comment: Incidentally, without your relevant HTML and CSS this question (basically "why isn't this working?") is unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on previous experience, despite the scarcity of information in the question itself, I'd suggest:

```
li {
    /* moves the marker inside the 'li' elements, to be included
       within the backgrounded area: */
    list-style-position: inside;
    /* adjust to taste: */
    padding-left: 2em;
}
```